# Can I add EAS support to Mac OS

Tags: email, contacts, calendar

Is there a plugin, or some third party solution that I can install on OSX to get EAS support for native calendars and contacts apps?

I'd like to add "internet accounts" in the settings for my hotmail calendars and contacts, which use EAS (Exchange ActiveSync).

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2014, there are no third-party OS X applications or plug-ins that support Exchange ActiveSync.  There aren't any solutions to view your Hotmail calendar and contacts in an OS X desktop application.